# How to align a toggle in css

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, toggle, toggleswitch

I'm trying to make a custom toggle button in react JS with CSS (using Sass). But now I am facing a problem, I can't align my switch button with the part behind.

The button is in position absolute, and the other one in position relative. I tried with flex (justify-content left, align items center) and I triend with various disply, (inline block and margin auto, inline-block and vertical align middle) but nothing worked for me.

AS you see in the pictures, my toggle is working but I am really triggering with the alignement.

Please excuse my english and my code, I am a beginner so if you have comment or if I can make thing easier let me know.

```
    <label className="toggle">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={isToggled}
        onClick={callback}
        name="ToggleSwitch"
        className="toggle__checkbox"
      />
      <span className="toggle__button" />
    </label>
```

```
@import '../../sass/variables';

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;



  &__checkbox {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;

    &:checked+.toggle__button {
      background-color: $primary-color;

      &:before {
        transform: translateX(20px);
        background-color: white;

      }
    }
  }

  &__button {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #646566;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 30px;

    &::before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
      background-color: #B6B6B6;
      border-radius: 60px;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
  }

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: CSS questions are best presented with HTML, no app code.

Comment: It would be easier to analyze the code in a snippet. However, on first look it seems that you just need to take into account the height difference. `.toggle` has height 20px and ` &::before` has height 25px. So in position absolute you need something like top: -2.5px, not 0. Perhaps make height 24px or 26px so that you can use a round number?

Comment: @IvanBeliakov I tried it but it doesn't work for what I am trying to do. The toggle's height must be smaller than the round button. Changing the top value change my toggle's height either (is it norma btw ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `transform:translateY(-50%);` to `.toggle__button::before` and `transform: translate(20px, -50%);` to `.toggle__checkbox:checked+.toggle__button:before`

```css
:root{background-color:black;}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  display:block;
}

.toggle__checkbox {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.toggle__checkbox:checked+.toggle__button {
  background-color: green;
}

.toggle__checkbox:checked+.toggle__button:before {
  transform: translate(20px, -50%);
  background-color: white;
}

.toggle__button {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #646566;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.toggle__button::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #B6B6B6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<label class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ToggleSwitch" class="toggle__checkbox" />
  <span class="toggle__button"></span>
</label>
```